# "ssexp" command is not working to start visual sourcesafe explorer

Tags: command-line, visual-sourcesafe, visual-sourcesafe-2005

If anyone knows how to start visual sourcesafe explorer, please write steps. I followed the steps mentioned in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h8d728xa%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) but it is giving error.

```
'ssexp' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you successfully install Source Safe 2005?  See:

[How to: Install Visual SourceSafe on a Client Machine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms181051%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

[How to: Install Visual SourceSafe on the Server Machine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms181050%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Did you use the CD command to navigate to the directory for the Visual SourceSafe installation?  That error message usually means you are not in the correct directory.